# Ajax file upload with formData fails on large files

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, upload, form-data

I'm sending via ajax a FormData object containing uploads files but when I try to upload large files (> 5M), I receive empty $_POST and $_FILES variables.

Reading so much posts about this issue I applied almost everything but didn't work.

```
I've tried on php.ini:
- max_execution_time = 300
- max_input_time = 300
- post_max_size = 2048M (large but compulsory)
- upload_max_filesize = 2048M (large but compulsory)
- max_input_vars = 2000 (trying different values)

On HTTP/HTTPS directives (some have no sense but I was trying in a desperately way to see the behaviour):
- FcgidConnectTimeout 300
- FcgidIOTimeout 300
- FcgidIdleTimeout 300
- FcgidBusyTimeout 300
- IPCCommTimeout 9999
- FcgidMaxRequestLen 21474836480
```

My code looks as follows:

```
var form = $('form[name="myform"]');
var formData = new FormData(form[0]);

/*
Also tried this:
   var file = $("form[name='myform'] input[name='filename']");
   formData.append("my_upload", (file[0]).files[0]);
*/

$.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   data: formData,
   dataType: 'json',
   async: true,
   url: '/mysite/controllers/Controller.php',
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
   ...
});
```

So, for files < 5M everything works perfect in both my local server and production server. For files > 5M only works on my local server but not in the production server (where I receive empty $_POST and $_FILES variables). They have in general some variables configuration although production server is under a WAF on CloudFlare.

Comment: It does sound like a file size limitation. Are you certain you updated the config files successfully? Have you debugged the error that's raised?

Comment: you should make sure that you are editing the correct `php.ini`, identify it with `php --ini` should appear in the Loaded Configuration File line, in my case `Loaded Configuration File: /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini`. There change values to upload_max_filesize, max_file_uploads, post_max_size

Comment: Yes I edited the correct php.ini: # php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.0/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         **/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini**

Comment: Debugging this is what I get: "TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
    at Function.invokeGetter (<anonymous>:2:14)"

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue on my setup. I am not using jQuery but vanilla js.

The Problem is not the server! If you have a look into the developer tools of your browser you can see that the HTTP-Request has no form data.

Small Upload <6MB is fine

[image: Small Upload <6MB is fine]

Big Upload >=6MB doesn't create FormData:

[image: Big Upload >=6MB doesn't create FormData]

My Code is:

```
function uploadFile(file, filename, domDirectory, domTabelle, domSchluessel){
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("filename", filename);
fd.append("name", filename);
fd.append("right_id", domDirectory);
fd.append("tabelle", domTabelle);
fd.append("schluessel", domSchluessel);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var reader  = new FileReader();
reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    fd.append("dataURI", reader.result);
    //console.log(reader.result);
    xhr.send(fd);
  }, false
);
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
xhr.open('POST', '../control/Upload.php', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the reason. Thank you to all of you and sorry for forgetting to explain what happened finally. It was the WAF from CloudFlare!, which limits the upload size to 5M. Yes, that's the reason. So I changed my code to make uploads divided in parts smaller than 5M and then join them again in the server once they are uploaded. I didn't find any better approach but hey, it works!.